# How to include white spaces in next() without using nextLine() in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make the user input a string, which can both contain spaces or not. So in that, I'm using NextLine();

However, i'm trying to search a text file with that string, therefore i'm using next() to store each string it goes through with the scanner, I tried using NextLine() but it would take the whole line, I just need the words before a comma.
 so far here's my code

```
System.out.print("Cool, now give me your Airport Name: ");

String AirportName = kb.nextLine();
AirportName = AirportName + ",";

while (myFile.hasNextLine()) {
    ATA = myFile.next();
    city = myFile.next();

    country = myFile.next();
    myFile.nextLine();
    // System.out.println(city);

    if (city.equalsIgnoreCase(AirportName)) {
        result++;
        System.out.println("The IATA code for "+AirportName.substring(0, AirportName.length()-1) + " is: " +ATA.substring(0, ATA.length()-1));
        break;
    }
}
```

The code works when the user inputs a word with no spaces, but when they input two words, the condition isn't met.

the text file just includes a number of Airports, their IATA, city, and country. Here's a sample:

```
ADL, Adelaide, Australia
IXE, Mangalore, India
BOM, Mumbai, India
PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia
```

Comment: not sure you're going about this in the easiest way. Can you post a sample of exactly what file you are trying to parse and what you want to keep?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am doing it the hard way, but I'm using code I know, and I'm still a beginner. 

It's a text file that contains several lines, each line contains IATA code, city, and country, as I mentioned above. 

Everyline is the same, but different codes, city..etc. 
I'm trying to write a software that prompts the user to input an Airport name (city) and the prog will search the document and will print out the IATA code. I am pretty much done with the program.

Comment: P.S I (kind of) solved my issue by splitting the input string, then adding if(string contains a space) then assign the first part to a string
then I used that string in a condition to compare only to the first word, and they are all unique so i pretty much have only one result.

This is how I solved it, I'm pretty sure it's not the optimal solution, but hey it's working for me :D Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, next() searches for first whitespace as a delimiter. You can change this behaviour like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
s.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
```

By this, `s.next()` will match commas as delimiters for your input (preceeded or followed by zero or more whitespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Here's an example:

```
String test = "ADL, Adelaide, Australia\n"
            + "IXE, Mangalore, India\n"
            + "BOM, Mumbai, India\n"
            + "PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia\n";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(test);
String strings[] = null;

while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    // ",\\s" matches one comma followed by one white space ", "
    strings = scan.nextLine().split(",\\s");

    for(String tmp: strings) {
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ADL
Adelaide
Australia
IXE
Mangalore
India
BOM
Mumbai
India
PPP
Proserpine Queensland
Australia
```